# how to pass value into templatetag from template in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have very basic question,gone through many blogs and django documentation but its bit confusing .could any help with below scenario.

**Scenario** :

i have x table in that four columns

```
 columns : **id  name    date         data **  
              1   ab    2011-02-03     p
              2   bc    2011-02-03     A
              3   ab    2011-02-04     A
              4   bc    2011-02-04     P
              5   ab    2011-02-05     B
              6   bc    2011-02-06     P
```

id a query to x like

res = x.objects.all()

it generates below output

```
[<x: ab  2011-02-03 P>, <x: bc 2011-02-03  A >, <x: ab  2011-02-04 A> , <x: bc  2011-02-04 P>,<x: ab  2011-02-05 b>,<x: ab 2011-02-06 P>]
```

now i write a res to template like belowformart

```
   {% load xyz %}

  {% for fetch in res : %}
       {{fetch.name}}
       {{fetch.date | xyz  }}
       {{ template tag result }}
```

in templatetag  needs able get the date from template and result that days data status back to template

Final output should like this

```
**name   2011-02-03 2011-02-04 2011-02-05 2011-02-06**
 ab      P           A          B
 bc      A           P                      P
```

sorry for long text,its kind of urgent, i need to implement in app by friday.

plzzz need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create class that will correspond to the table you are trying to output.

I.e. something along the lines:

```
Class MyTable:
   def __init__(self):
      self.dates = [] // where dates[i] might be something like {date: [P, A, ...]}
                      // you will have to figure out how and what do you want to represent
      self.data = []  // where data[i] is something like {ab:[P, A, B, None]}

   // define different methods to fill dates and data fields
```

And then you fill MyTable's fields with data from res and pass MyTable to template.

Then you just pass your filled table to template. It will have one to one corresponds with your table, so you just iterate through rows and print them.